# Access deeper-level list items inside nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, slice

I have a data structure that consists of nested dictionaries and lists..

```
System1 -- Charge1 -- Ion1 -- Ion2 -- List of Values
        -- Charge2 -- Ion1 -- Ion2 -- List of Values
        -- Charge2 -- Ion2 -- Ion4 -- List of Values
        -- Charge2 -- Ion3 -- Ion4 -- List of Values
System2 -- Charge1 -- Ion1 -- Ion2 -- List of Values
... and so on
```

SystemX is the key in the highest-level (level 0) dict, ChargeX is a key in level 1 dict, IonX in lvl2, IonX (second instance) in lvl3 and then we have a list type object which holds certain values I want to use in a function.

Now, if those were all lists and I would want to use all values for a certain IonX-IonX combination (in that order), could I slice it with `function(data[:][:]["Ion1"]["Ion2"])`?

Either way I searched around for quite a while now and could not really find questions I feel addressed the same issue...

**How do I best go forward using my dictionaries structure?**

*Is it a good idea to iterate over all keys in each dictionary until I reach the desired level(s) and return all the lists of values if existing into a new dictionary/list?*
Is that the simplest, most elegant or even most pythonic way? I can't really believe it is..

I really don't know how I would achieve my goal using list comprehension right now, but I guess I could figure something out although it might turn out quite ugly.

I have virtually no experience using generators and `yield`, although it seems it could help. If you suggest such an approach, I would kindly ask you to explain in more detail.

Thank you all in advance. Hope you guys can help me out here. Really stuck.

Cheers, BUFU

Comment: Out of curiosity, are all of the "List of Values" the same size?  This might be a good place to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: Are there other places in the code where the System -> Charge -> Ion hierarchy is important?  You could reshape your data (or copy it and reshape the copy) to make the Ions the primary keys.

Comment: @0x5453 no, unfortunately not. But thanks for the link. Will check these DataFrames out.

Comment: For reshaping the data: It would lead to the same problem at a different part of the workflow.. with the features swapped...

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to loop over the value lists and print them out, but probably pandas is more effective in terms of speed and readability as suggested by @ 0x5453 in the comments ..

```
data = {
    "System1": {"Charge1": {"Ion1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                            "Ion2": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                            },
                "Charge2": {"Ion1": [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                            "Ion2": [16,17, 18, 19, 20]
                            },
                },
    "System2": {"Charge1": {"Ion1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                            "Ion2": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                            },
                "Charge2": {"Ion1": [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                            "Ion2": [16,17, 18, 19, 20]
                            }
                }
}


def simple_function(data):
    for systems in data.keys():
        for charges in data[str(systems)]:
            for ions in data[str(systems)][str(charges)]:
                for value_lists in data[str(systems)][str(charges)][str(ions)]:
                    print(f"{value_lists = }")


simple_function(data)
```

Comment: @BUFU tell me what your function seeks to achieve and I will work it into my attempt of answering as well.

Comment: Hey Gustav! That is basically what I do most of the time, when I loop over everything... I just hoped there would be an easier way to give only part of the whole tree over to the function (where I do NOT need all the values).. I guess I write a helper function to loop over everything, sort out which ones I need and return only those, so I can basically "filter" out what I need and do something like ```function(filterfunc(data, i1="Ion1", i2="Ion3"))```. The function makes a histogram of the values for each System/Charge combination. (And other stuff probably later on.)

Comment: Oh, and I should clarify that I have two levels of "ions" with the same keys actually but order matters and that might complicate matters even more in terms of a solution... although with this approach it doesn't really matter.

Comment: How about applying a lambda to the filter function? Something like list(filter(lambda i1, i2: i1 == "Ion1" and i2 == "Ion3", ion_list))

Comment: That might be a good ansatz. I will try it and get back when I have a working solution.